# Not able to create AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I try to create AVD. But Create button is deactive

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your SDK Manager and make sure everything required for API lv 17 is downloaded and installed

Answer (score 0):

You need to download a system image for the SDK you are trying to target.  You don't have everything you need, which is why you can't create the AVD.

Comment: Where I can download it?

Comment: you can access it by clicking the small android icon below the "Navigate" label

Answer (score 0):

Under `CPU/ABI` it says "No system images installed for this target." Download the system images using the SDK Manager.