# Android virtual device creation

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am novice at android development. Have problem with creating Android Virtual Device (AVD).  When I go to Eclipse -> Android Virtual Device Manager -> Device Definitions -> Choose any device from list -> Create AVD... window for AVD creation appears. However, for any options I have OK button unclickable. Why I face this problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select a compatible target version in the AVD creation window for the OK button to be enabled. If you don't have a compatible version, try updating your SDK if you haven't and install all available updates.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download required files using your SDK Manager. Make sure the target matches (if you have downloaded level 17 API you must select API lvl 17 as target for the new AVD)
The same question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216622/not-able-to-create-avd/14216721#14216721) a couple hours ago

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set "AVD Name", "RAM", "VM Heap" and "Internal Storage". Also make sure the device you've chosen is compatible with the Target API, new devices are not compatible with older APIs

Comment: that is not about "new devices", you have to set the target explicitly while creating the AVD, no matter if you use older or newer APIs